# Sending logs from kubernetes pods to Splunk

Tags: kubernetes

I am in the process to move from Docker Swarm to Kubernetes. All is going well, except for logging to Splunk.
In Docker Compose I used the Splunk logging driver:

```
[...]
    logging:
      driver: splunk
      options:
        splunk-token: 5af9292c-abba-beef-abba-7dc41b92e740
        splunk-url: https://splunk.example.org:8088
        splunk-format: json
        splunk-sourcetype: docker_dev
        splunk-source: docker
        splunk-index: dev
        splunk-verify-connection: "false"
        splunk-insecureskipverify: "true"
```

This made `stdout` from the container sent directly to Splunk via HEC.

However, how can I convert this setup to Kubernetes?

Some suggested Fluentd, but as I understand I need a Fluentd-server in between the Kubernetes-cluster and Splunk?
And I have also looked at [Splunk OpenTelemetry Collector for Kubernetes](https://github.com/signalfx/splunk-otel-collector-chart/tree/main), but I am still unsure if it is the right choice for collecting the logs and sending them to Splunk? Or is it meant for something else, like metrics?